# Why does sns.heatmap generate this error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, correlation

I can't seem to figure out what these errors are and am not sure how to get it resolved. I'm a beginner in python.

Am trying to execute this code:

```
plt.figure(figsize= [10,7])

sns.heatmap(appl_data[irrev+["TARGET"]].corr(), cmap="Reds",annot=true)

plt.title("Correlation between EXT_SOURCE_3, EXT_SOURCE_2, TARGET", fontdict={"fontsize":20}, pad=25)
plt.show()
```

This is the error showing up after I try to execute the above code:
[Correlation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqYRe.png)

Am not sure how to get it resolved

Comment: Can you give a [minimum reproducible example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Not sure what any of your variable in your code mean, and KEY ERROR is usually when key is not present in the dict.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your error seems due to a missing key while your description and tags say otherwise. Please while adding an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), edit the description and the tags as well.